# How to compile a single java file among multiple files in the same folder with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I am new to gradle. I have a project. Within that lot of main classes along with its dependent classes are present under the same folder/package.

EG:

```
default package
     ---class1.java
     ---class2.java
     ---class3.java
     ---class1dependencyclass.java
```

Within that build doing `gradle build` the jar file created only with class1 and its class1dependencyclass. Other files need not to be build in that jar. Jar should have the class1 and its dependencies alone.

How can I do it? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating java library project using below command

```
gradle init --type java-library
```

This will create project structure for you to begin with.

Comment: I don't have build.gradle file. My java project is looked like above mentioned structure only.